# Django context processor - 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to build dynamic sidebar with context processor. I take distinct values for sidebar from database table.

Here's my context processor:

```
from clients.models import client
def sidebar(request):
        return {'clientlist': client.objects.order_by('name').distinct('name')}
```

In views.py I have following code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader, RequestContext
from clients.models import client
def index(request):
        allclientlist = client.objects.all()
        return render (request, 'clients/index.html', {'allclientlist': allclientlist}, context_instance=RequestContext(request, processors=['sidebar']))
```

`allclientlist` used to generate a table with all clients and their data. Next I'm trying to build dynamic sidebar with context processor and get following traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/root/projects/webapp/clients/views.py" in index
  7.    return render (request, 'clients/index.html', {'allclientlist': allclientlist}, context_instance=RequestContext(request, processors=['sidebar']))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py" in __init__
  179.             self.update(processor(request))

Exception Type: TypeError at /clients/
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
```

It worked when it was like:

```
def index(request):
       allclientlist = client.objects.all()
       clientlist = client.objects.order_by('name').distinct('name')
       return render(request, 'clients/index.html', {'allclientlist': allclientlist, 'clientlist': clientlist})
```

But to make this menu available in all views, I needed to have `clientlist` declaration in all views. I wanted to avoid this and stuck. Please, help me to find this error.

Comment: Either `processor` or `self.update` is a string; search your codebase for both names and figure out which one you defined wrong.

Comment: `processors=['sidebar']` does not look callable to me. Replace it with your actual function and it should work :)

Comment: But my actual function is a 'sidebar' :) I took this part of code from djangobook, because I wasn't sure is my code right or not.

Comment: @Wolph means to use `processors[sidebar]` (i.e. passing the function object `sidebar`), instead of `processors['sidebar']`, (i.e passing the string `'sidebar'`). This would prevent the error you are getting. However, for most use cases, you shouldn't have to use the `context_instance` argument when using the render shortcut, which I've tried to explain in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `clientlist` included in all views, then add `client.models.sidebar` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting, and remove the `context_instance` argument from the `render` call in your view - when you use the `render` shortcut, the template is automatically rendered with a request context.

```
def index(request):
    allclientlist = Client.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'clients/index.html', {'allclientlist': allclientlist})
```

As an aside, the Django convention would be to move the sidebar context processor into a `client.context_processors` module, and to capitalise your model as `Client`.

Comment: It is in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS:<br/>  
>>> from django.conf import settings<br/>  
>>> settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS<br/>  
('django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 'django.core.context_processors.debug', 'django.core.context_processors.i18n', 'django.core.context_processors.media', 'django.core.context_processors.static', 'django.core.context_processors.tz', 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages', 'clients.templateprocessors.sidebarprocessor.sidebar')

Comment: That looks ok if the sidebar method is in a module `client.templateprocessors.sidebarprocessor`. Have you removed the context_instance argument from your render call? What error do you get now?

Comment: Now, it looks like `return render (request, 'clients/index.html', {'allclientlist': allclientlist}, 'sidebar')`  And the error is: `render_to_string() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context_instance'`

Comment: I've added a code snippet to my answer. You need to remove the final argument `sidebar`.

Comment: It works, thank you, but... why? I thought that I should define somehow in view, that I will use context processor.

Comment: With the [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response) you do have to specify that you want your template rendered with a request context, but with the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response) shortcut it happens automatically.